# How can I cap so the user can only type in one space bar in java JTextField

Tags: java, eclipse, string, swing, space

I need to make sure the user can not type more than two string words into this text box and only use one space bar but not really sure how to write this code. I have everything else working fine!

Comment: Add the code you tried with.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for an InputVerifier: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that code helps with this problem?

Comment: Did you try anything? You have to add an InputVerifier to your text box.